# Rewrite rule not working as expected

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Here is my .htaccess code,

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /view-([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$
RewriteRule ^view-([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)/$ post.php?id=$1

</IfModule>
```

i.e, id=$1 = my-first-&-thread++ from post.php file.

the link become

```
http://site.com/view-my-first-&-thread++/
```

and gives error 404.

I want my link to be like this:

```
http://site.com/view-my-first-thread/
```

How could this possible? plz help

Comment: It would be easier if you tell us what you want to do, for example redirect my ugly url `http://domain.com/post.php?id=blabla&1203` to `http://domain.com/view-my-first-thread/1203`

Comment: I want to remove character like +,$,& etc. from URL's.

Comment: It is still unclear what is being asked here. What is the starting URL and what do you want it to be as target? If you remove `+,$,& etc. from URL's` then internal URL will become `/post.php?id=view-my-first-thread` instead of /post.php?id=view-my-first-&-thread++` how will that help? Isn't `post.php` doing a lookup based on passed GET parameter `id` ?

Answer (score 0):

The regex you're using in the `RewriteRule` won't match your example URL, as it excludes both `+` and `&`. Sometimes, by allowing specific characters, you implicitly exclude other ones you may want.

Try changing the rule to match anything *except* a slash (`/`):

```
RewriteRule ^view-([^/]+)/$` post.php?id=$1
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need `B` flag of `mod_rewrite` here.

```
RewriteRule ^view-([^/]+)/?$ post.php?id=$1 [L,QSA,NC,B]
```

This will redirect to `http://site.com/view-my-first-&-thread++/` to `http://site.com/post.php?id=my-first-&-thread++`